# Adding Data to an Existing Excel File in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

[Link to error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY9K0.png)

I am writing a program to take some measurements and store them in an Excel file. I have a 'Do Test' button that, when clicked, creates an excel sheet, does a test, stores the results in a dataGridView, and then exports the dataGridView to Excel. This works perfectly the first time, but when I click the button again for a second test, a new Excel sheet is created (rather than editing the existing one), and the program crashes. I want the program to just add another few rows of data to the existing spreadsheet without overwriting the whole document.

Here's my UPDATED code. The first button click calls CreateExcel() and WriteToNewExcel(), and the second click just calls WriteToExistingExcel().

```
     private void CreateExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create excel sheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Create headings
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Bandwidth (Hz)";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Centre of marker search range (Hz)";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Qf              ";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Loss (dB)             ";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Shape Factor";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

            //Autofit column widths
            Cellrange = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5]];
            Cellrange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            //Save excel sheet
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("S:\\User Shares\\Lucy\\Lucy's Files\\Anechoic Chamber\\Anechoic Program\\Excel File\\Data",
                Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Error in editing Excel");
        }
    }

    //Write to excel function

    private void WriteToNewExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            //Add heading
            int TestNumber = 1;
            int RowNumber = 2;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[RowNumber, 1] = "Test " + TestNumber;
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5]].Merge();
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5].EntireRow.Font.Italic = true;


            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 3, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            ++TestNumber;
            RowNumber = (TestNumber - 1) * 13;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Error in editing Excel");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xlWorkSheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            }
            if (xlWorkBook != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            }
            if (xlApp != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteToExistingExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("S:\\User Shares\\Lucy\\Lucy's Files\\Anechoic Chamber\\Anechoic Program\\Excel File\\Data",
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Add heading
            int TestNumber = 2;
            int RowNumber = 13;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[RowNumber, 1] = "Test " + TestNumber;
            xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[RowNumber, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[RowNumber, 5]].Merge();


            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 16, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            ++TestNumber;
            RowNumber = RowNumber + 13;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Error in editing Excel");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xlWorkSheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            }
            if (xlWorkBook != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            }
            if (xlApp != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
        }

    }
```

But then I got this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. xlApp was null.' on the first click of the test button.

Edit 2:
This is my code for the button click:

```
           private void button_StartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NumberOfClick == 1)
        {
            CreateExcel();

            MoveAndMeasure();
            WriteToNewExcel();
            KillAllGroups();
            InitializeAllGroups();
            HomeAllGroups();
        }
        else
        {
            MoveAndMeasure();
            WriteToExistingExcel();
            KillAllGroups();
            InitializeAllGroups();
            HomeAllGroups();
        }
        ++NumberOfClick;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending data to existing Excel file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841251/appending-data-to-existing-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you - I seem to have a similar problem to this other asker but I cannot figure out what bit of code he used to fix it!

Comment: Well, in the big picture what appears to lacking in the code is… if you open an existing Excel file with existing data… your code is going to have to go and find the next available empty row index in the Excel file. Once you have that row index, you will know which row to start writing to. The link is a simple method that takes a row index and uses it as the starting row index when adding data to the worksheet. The current code for writing to an existing file always starts at the same row index. Hence, overwriting any existing data.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is my issue - when I click the second time, a whole new Excel doc is created, separate to my original file. The data on the original file is not overwritten, but I don't know why the second file is created. I've attached an image, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi yeah I've looked at this other question again and I don't think it's the same issue - I think mine is something to do with how the excel sheet is saved/opened/accessed in order for the program to somehow create two files and a path error

Comment: After a closer look at the code… it not surprising to see an error. In two of the methods it appears the Excel application, `Workbook` and `Worksheet` are all global variables. Those objects need to be disposed of when done. Nowhere in the code are those resources disposed of. In the two methods that create and write to existing… those methods “create” a new Excel application and either create or open an existing file… do some work… then leave. This is leaving those lost COM objects OPEN.

Comment: I bet there are MANY Excel apps running… check the task manager after running the code a few times. Minimum, you should “wrap” all the Excel code in a try/catch/finally construct. In the `finally` portion of code you need to “close”, “quit” and “release” those COM objects.

Comment: Thanks for this - does this mean that I have to close the entire Excel application every time I want to edit it?

Comment: _”does this mean that I have to close the entire Excel application every time I want to edit it?”_ … technically NO. But why leave it open? You have no idea “when” or even “if” the user will run it again. It is proper for the code (methods) to “release” ALL the objects IT creates. Given this, even though technically you “could” leave the Excel app open, I see not reason to do so.

Comment: I just want the excel file to stay open, and then each set of data to appear in it, each time I press the 'test' button - and then the user can manually close it when they are finished with all their testing. It seems clunky to create the sheet, close it, and then close and reopen it every time new data is added? Plus I tried adding some close/quit functions and my program still crashes (see above). Sorry if I am misunderstanding at all, I am very new to this.

Comment: Form the image we can clearly see that you have created a second new file, so `CreateExcel()` must have been called again. Don't do that, because you can't save it with the same file name a second time

Comment: I don't think CreateExcel() has been called again, unless my button function is incorrect? I've added it above

Comment: It is wrong. `NumberOfClick` is a local variable. It will be initialized each time the method is called. Learn how do debug, please. Press the Pause button and go through your code step by step, so you can see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I've only been coding for a few weeks! I've fixed the click function now, thank you, but now I get an error that Excel cannot access the file because a) the path does not exist, b) the file is being used b y another program or c) the workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook. Is this because I didn't release the file after the first click?

Comment: Bear in mind, the finally will execute even if there was an exception thrown. So you need to make sure the `xlApp` and `xlWorkBook` are not null BEFORE you try to close, quit or release. The try/catch/finally should be something like… BEFORE the `try`, create the variables `xlApp` and `xlWorkBook` and set each to `null`. Then… in the `finally`… check to see if `xlApp` or `xlWorkBook` are `null` BEFORE you try to close, quit or release.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I have edited my 'finally' function and made sure my variables are null to begin with. It's definitely running better now, but I still get an error message (link to image in post) that the path cannot be found, and an error is caught in WriteToExistingExcel()

Comment: I've updated my full code now with what I've now got

Comment: Are you aware, that in the last code snippet, the... `button_StartTest_Click` ... the variable `NumberOfClick` will ALWAYS be 1. And the `else` portion will NEVER execute.

Comment: I've made NumberOfClick a global variable now, and the second click is working - it takes measurements and puts them in dataGridView - but only until the data needs to be written to excel, when it can't find the path. I've updated the code above to show this.

Comment: Let me know, I can post an example that may help. HOWEVER, I am still missing something here… You stated that… “_I just want the excel file to stay open, and then each set of data to appear in it, each time I press the 'test' button - and then the user can manually close it when they are finished with all their testing.”_ ??? … what does _“finished with all their testing”_ mean?

Comment: If the user adds the grid data to the Excel file… what else is needed to be done by the user? In other words, what does the user need to do to in the Excel file that cannot be done in your code? I am just trying to point out that leaving the Excel file open is a bad idea for many reasons.

Comment: Hi - I want to leave the window open so that the user can take multiple measurements, view all the results, and then close the window when they are finished taking/comparing/using the results. If the window closed automatically then the user would have to find and reopen it if they actually wanted to view or manipulate the results at all

Comment: Why is leaving the file open like this a bad idea?

Comment: If you want to leave the file open… go for it… You have not answered my question… once the Excel file is open, what exactly is the user going to be doing in the Excel file that can not be done in your code? You state that… _”I want to leave the window open so that the user can take multiple measurements, view all the results, and then close the window when they are finished taking/comparing/using the results.”_ ? … what does this mean? What is the user _”taking multiple measurements”_ of and how is the user doing this? How is the user _”viewing”_ all the results? What results?

Comment: Again my question is “why” is the user doing this IN the Excel file instead of doing _”multiple measurements and viewing the results”_ … in your code? Why can’t the user do all this BEFORE the Excel file is opened? This is not clear and I am curious as to “what” the user is doing in the Excel file that can not be done in your code. Please forgive me if I am missing something, however, this whole approach just seems odd. Why use your code to open the Excel file? Couldn’t the user simply open the Excel file, then copy/paste that data from your code?

Comment: Okay so - all I want is a simple program. The user clicks a 'start test' button. This causes some instrumentation to take some measurements, return them, and store them in a datagridview AND a newly opened excel sheet. The user can then view the results. The NEXT TIME the user presses the 'start test' button, the procedure will repeat, but the results will be copied over into a new row in the EXISTING OPEN excel sheet. The user can then view, edit, and compare the results. If the button is clicked again, the process repeats etc. etc.

Comment: I don't want the user to have to copy and paste the results themselves to avoid errors, and I don't want the excel sheet to keep opening and closing as it would be distracting.

Comment: This way the user can view, store, edit the results of the test as they please, rather than being limited to the datagridview in my program.